# Have got id of clicked button in React but then want to use that id within an if

Tags: reactjs, spfx

I have a Next and Prev button below a list on my spfx based webpart.
I also have another list below it with another two Next and Prev buttons.

I want to distinguish between the two sets of buttons and use the two functions that I'm using already:

```
private _listANext(e) {

    let currentPage = this.state.ListAPage; 
    let highestPageNo = this.state.ListAPages;

    currentPage = Math.min(highestPageNo,currentPage + 1 );
    this.setState({
      ListAPage: currentPage,

    });
    console.log(e.target.id);
  }

  private _listAPrev(e) {
    let currentPage = this.state.ListAPage; 
    currentPage = currentPage <= 1 ? 1 : currentPage - 1;
    this.setState({
      ListAPage: currentPage,
    });
    console.log(e.target.id);
  }
```

and the buttons in the render:

```
<DefaultButton
         id="aprev"
         text="Prev"
         onClick={(e) => this._listAPrev(e)}
         />
       <span> {' '}</span>
<DefaultButton
         id="anext"
         text="Next"
         onClick={(e) => this._listANext(e)}
         />
```

The two functions give me the id of the buttons but if I were to use the id's within an `if`, would the id's stay the same on different browsers? I think there is a better way to do what I'm trying to do!

Comment: I'm not fully understanding what your problem is. The `id` would stay the same in different browsers, did you run into a problem making you think otherwise? Using the `id` in an `if` is totally fine as long as it's within scope. Where are you trying to use it?

Comment: Hi Brian, the id was different for the button between Edge and Chrome.
I accepted the below answer because it allowed me to use the id that I assigned to the button, within an if function. This allowed me to distinguish between the two different sets of buttons. I could have been lazy and just made separate functions for the two sets of buttons, but I wanted to make it a little tighter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<DefaultButton
         id="aprev"
         text="Prev"
         onClick={(e) => this._listAPrev(e,id)}
         />
```

you can pass the id by this.and get the id and use it.

```
private _listAPrev(e,id) {}
```

Comment: It doesn't let me assign an id, the id logs as 'id__46'

Comment: also it shows error on id in render - cannot find name id

Comment: add like onClick={(e) => this._listAPrev(e,"aprev")}  and vice versa

Comment: Tried that. It still doesn't change the id of the button

Comment: I get the "aprev" in the log when I click the button, so the id is being passed through....so I can use that I guess